# React.js - Clear controlled textarea initial value on focus

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In [this example](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-textarea-tag) for a controlled textarea, it shows how to set an initial value and then update the value onChange. How can you clear this initial value when the field is focused for the first time without clearing any further input from the user.

Setting the initial value:

```
this.state = {
  value: 'Please write an essay'
};
```

I assume you would do something like:

```
<textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} onFocus={this.handleFocus} />
```

Then have:

```
  handleFocus(event) {
    this.setState({value: ''});
  }
```

Although this isn't working. Any advice?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZVeWB?editors=0010

Comment: `onFocus={this.handleFocus.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a function to a component, like an event handler, the "this" capture is lost. When the textarea calls your event handler, "this" will not refer to the component where that function was defined. I think it will actually refer to the event handler function its self.

The usual way of getting around this is binding 'this' to the event handler:

```
onFocus={this.onFocus.bind(this)}
```

You can also define your methods as lambda member variables if you're using ES7:

```
class MyComponnet {
  onFocus = (e) => { ... }
  render() {
    return <textarea onFocus={this.onFocus} />
  }
}
```

This works because lambdas in js automatically capture everything around them. it looks a bit cleaner.

Also, you should consider using a placeholder attribute instead:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_placeholder.asp

Comment: Thanks, good explanation. I should have just went with placeholder instead!

Answer (score 1):

You missed to `bind` your `handleFocus` method in a `constructor` function

```
this.handleFocus  = this.handleFocus.bind(this)
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the bind (doh!) but once corrected still have the issue of the value being reset after each focus. Sava's answer below using a `placeholder` instead works great.